# Creating documents in Elasticsearch after save/update in Elixir Phoenix

Tags: elasticsearch, nosql, elixir, phoenix-framework

I'm trying to figure out the best flow to insert/update a document into elasticsearch (or any nosql database really) after creating a new row in a SQL database, and where to put the logic in Elixir Phoenix.

Imagine my SQL tables are `posts` has_many `comments`, and my elasticsearch structure has a `posts` index where `comments` is a nested document, so I could search/retrieve the post and comment content at the same time. Meaning if a user creates or updates their comment's message, the related `post` document in elasticsearch should update.

What would be the best approach?

Answer (score 1):

The exact implementation probably depends on a couple things: how fast are the operations and does the user need to know the outcome?

If both operations are reasonably fast (i.e. the user can wait), then you could use a simple `with` statement to ensure both successfully complete, e.g.

```
with {:ok, _result1} <- update_postgres(data),
  {:ok, _result2} <- update_elasticsearch(data) do
   {:ok, "Everything updated!"}
end
```

If you need a bit more formality around "binding" 2 operations together, then an [Ecto transaction](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/composable-transactions-with-multi.html) does the job.  The docs usually assume that the operations are both database operations or that they use the same `Repo`, but you can do arbitrary tasks in your transaction, e.g. updating Elasticache:

```
  def two_things(data) do
    My.Repo.transaction fn ->
      with {:ok, _result1} <- update_postgres(data),
           {:ok, _result2} <- update_elasticache(data)
      do
        {:ok, "Everything updated!"}
      else
        {:error, e} -> 
           My.Repo.rollback(e)
           {:error, "Something failed!"}
    
      end
    end
  end
```

Using a transaction only really makes sense when you need to perform a rollback on failure.

The other option here assumes that the operations might be slow enough that you wouldn't want to keep the user waiting around for them to complete.  Usually the "primary" operation of critical importance is updating the database.  Sometimes the other related updates (e.g. in cache layers) are best left to an asynchronous side-effect.  For example:

```
result = update_postgres(data)
Task.async(fn -> update_elasticache(data) end)
result
```

Or perhaps trigger the side-effect only if the database operation is successful:

```
case update_postgres(data) do
  {:ok, result} -> 
    Task.async(fn -> update_elasticache(data) end)
    {:ok, result}
  {:error, error} -> {:error, error}
end
```

Or a bit cleaner syntax:

```
with {:ok, result} <- update_postgres(data) do
  Task.async(fn -> update_elasticache(data) end)
    {:ok, result}
end
```

There are many syntaxes/helpers that accomplish this, but the idea is that any secondary operations are non-blocking and can complete after returning a result to the user.